# Limit Filter Access to a Single Container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

Is it possible in an Azure storage account to generate a Shared Access Signature that has filter privilege to only a single Container within the account.

I know that searches can be scoped to a particular container, but I want the SAS to ensure that the filter operation can only take place on the specified container.

Kind Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by filter operation?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what you are trying to achieven and what mean by filter operation.

> I want the SAS to ensure that the filter operation can only take place
> on the specified container.

There is no such kind of activity possible with SAS. SAS is use to access to particuler resource for a specfic time period and you can also add up the permission to the SAS based on your requirement.